# how to remove json element using json parse in logic app?

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

Input json -

```
{
    "data": {
        "Testresults": [
            {
                "mydata": {
                    "id": "111",
                    "uri": "url",
                    "type": "demo"
                },
                "name": "",
                "address": "",
```

in side `Parse Json` schema added as below -

```
{
    "properties": {
        "data": {
            "properties": {
                "Testresults": {
                    "items": {
                        "properties": {
                            "name": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "address": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
```

I have removed `mydata` from `Parse Json` schema still in the output getting same input json.

I want to remove `mydata` element from input json and pass it further , what should be done for that in parseJson?

expected output after `Parse Json`

```
{
    "data": {
        "Testresults": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "address": "",
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, I post my steps below for your reference.

In my logic app, I use the json below as the input data:

```
{
    "data": {
        "Testresults": [
            {
                "mydata": {
                    "id": "111",
                    "uri": "url",
                    "type": "demo1"
                },
                "name": "Michael",
                "address": "abc"
            },
            {
                "mydata": {
                    "id": "222",
                    "uri": "url",
                    "type": "demo2"
                },
                "name": "Daniel",
                "address": "def"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

First I create a variable to store it.
[image]

Then, parse json.
[image]

After that, we can use liquid. We need to [create an integration account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account#create-integration-account) and [link to the logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account#link-to-logic-app), then [upload the liquid map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-liquid-transform#create-liquid-template-or-map-for-your-integration-account) shown as below:

```
{
    "data": {
        "Testresults": [
            {% for testresult in content.data.Testresults %}
            {
                "name": "{{testresult.name}}",
                "address": "{{testresult.address}}"
            },
            {% endfor %}
        ]
    }
}
```

Now, we can use "Transform JSON to JSON" action to do convert it.
[image]

Run the logic app, I get the result we expect.(without "mydata")
[image]

Hope it would be helpful to your requirement~

Comment: no without integration account client do not want that :( could you please help using parse json ? and there are 1000 more fields can not add those manually into script

Comment: Hi @Neo. As far as I know, "parse json" is just used to parse the json data and then we can use the fields in the next actions in logic app, but it can not be used to remove the element of the json data. So I think we can just do it by liquid or you can import a azure function to the logic app and do the convert in the function code.